# How do I create a quarter-over-quarter variance column or measure with a table of account balance totals by quarter?

Tags: powerbi, dax, formula, calculated-columns, variance

I have a table that lists quarter-end account balances by account and business group and I'd like to create a measure or column that shows the quarter-over-quarter balance change for each company/account combo (e.g., Group A, Account 10000 quarter-over-quarter change is $500).

I've tried various formulas using the calculate function, but these don't work if I don't apply aggregation (SUM and SUMX are what I've tried) to the AMOUNT column. The aggregations seem to mess up the results. I either get blank values or duplicate amount values. I think it's because the amounts don't need to be aggregated. They're already aggregated values.

How can I do a simple subtraction based on quarterly dates without having to aggregate my amount column?

The formula(and similar variations) I've tried:

```
QtrChange =
VAR CurrentAmt = TABLE1[AMOUNT]
VAR PrevAmt = CALCULATE(SUM(TABLE1[AMOUNT]), PREVIOUSQUARTER(TABLE1[DATE].[DATE])
RETURN = CurrentAmt - PrevAmt
```

**Table example:**

| Business Group | Account | Quarter end balance | Quarter |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 100000 | $2000 | 3/31/22 |
| A | 200000 | $3000 | 3/31/22 |
| B | 100000 | $4000 | 3/31/22 |
| B | 200000 | $5000 | 3/31/22 |

---

**Edit:**
Edited DAX formula with labels tying to example table, for better clarity:

```
QtrChange =   
VAR CurrentAmt = TABLE1[Quarter end balance]
    VAR PrevAmt = CALCULATE(SUM(TABLE1[Quarter end balance]), PREVIOUSQUARTER(TABLE1[Quarter].[DATE])
    RETURN = CurrentAmt - PrevAmt
```

Comment: Where's your sample data?

Comment: @Peter Is the example table insufficient? The intent was for that to be sample data.

Comment: You are referencing TABLE1[AMOUNT] as a column and in the next sentence it's an aggregated measure and where does this $500 quarter-over-quarter change come from? Imagine that the ones you're asking for help have no clue how your data model looks like.

Comment: @Peter, Ah, you can see the sample data, just having trouble following because the labels don't tie 1-for-1. Got it. 

Table 1 refers to the example table. The [Amount] column refers to the "Quarter end balance" column which displays an account amount. As stated, the formula I tried does not work without an aggregation, so in the DAX example provided, I showed the value aggregation I attempted to get the formula to work. This was unsuccessful. 

The $500 variance is a hypothetical example, as indicated by "e.g.". This is an example of what I'm trying to achieve, not what I've achieved.

Comment: You need a date table to reliably use time intelligence functions like PREVIOUSQUARTER().